# Closing all the opened chrome windows using selenium - python - osx

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have to download some files from a website, I'm using Python - Selenium - Chrome - Osx.

I have his code so far:

```
lnk = "www.foobar.com"
CHROMEDRIVER=webdriver.Chrome()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False, "name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
        "download.default_directory" : TEMP_DOWNLOAD}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",profile)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver.get(lnk)
while True:
    if filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob(TEMP_DOWNLOAD+'/*.crdownload')):
        pass
    else:
        break
driver.quit()
```

This code starts the download of the file, waits the end of the download and then closes the webdriver.

Everything is working properly except that it opens 2 Chrome windows, one to open the link and the other to download the file, and the quit() method closes only the latter.

Is there a way to kill all the windows opened by Selenium (I'm trying to avoid firing a terminal command to kill the processes brute force)?

EDIT:

as Mukesh Takhtani said in comment in my code the problem is a pointless webdriver instance.

Comment: I believe you dont require this line : CHROMEDRIVER=webdriver.Chrome(), can you try commenting this and run again?

Comment: thanks @mukesh-takhtani , that useless line was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use this. This I used for Firefox. You can use this for Chrome. Call kill_waste() in your python code and it would kill idle useless Chrome. Please note that this would work for OSX or FreeBSD. For Linux distros you would have to change the way you are going to use grep and cut

```
import commands

def kill_waste():

    (_,firefox_processes) = commands.getstatusoutput("ps -ax | grep '/usr/local/bin/firefox -foreground' | cut -c1-24")
    sleep(0.5)
    firefox_processes = firefox_processes.splitlines()

    for pid in firefox_processes:
        values = pid.split()
        time_value = values[3].split(':')

        if ((values[2] == 'I' or values[2] == 'I+') and time_value[0] == '1') or time_value[0] == '2':
            commands.getstatusoutput("kill -9 " + values[0])
```

Comment: this entire answer can be replaced with the one-liner: `$ killall firefox`

Comment: Observe I am finding "I" or "I+" Firefox and killing them. Killall is nice way to kill everything